# Getting "Illegal URL or an improperly formatted request" while trying to get access token through REST call

Tags: oauth2, apexrest

I am trying to get access token from salesforce to access apex rest API. For this i am trying to get  access token by sending request to

```
https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token
```

I am setting all required headers

```
  grant_type: password
    username: ****UserName****
    password: ***********
    client_id: 3MVG9ZL0ppGP5UrAK9L_2UlHYraxj5LVGwS1B_vyAIzVVE4jOdt4i.aJCYuioKS7VsCuokwWAm2uIZKSms
    client_secret: 543527409660481357
Content-Type : multipart/form-data
```

I am trying to connect form chrome rest client>But i am getting error saying

```
<html><body><table cellspacing=10>
<tr><td><span style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 12pt;">Illegal Request</span></td></tr>
<tr><td>You have sent us an Illegal URL or an improperly formatted request. </td></tr>
<tr><td></td></tr>
</table>

<!-- Body events -->
<script type="text/javascript">function bodyOnLoad(){if(window.PreferenceBits){window.PreferenceBits.prototype.csrfToken="null";};}function bodyOnBeforeUnload(){}function bodyOnFocus(){}function bodyOnUnload(){}</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I have created connected app and given all related details in headers too while requesting for token[image]

But i am confused about CallBackURL. What exactly should i give for this CallBackURL while accessing service from chrome rest client

Answer (score 4):

Everything in the config looks good to me. Here's is a thought. Do you have a % sign in your password? If you do you need to convert it to %25 to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Please correct following errors.

1. set Content-Type to **application/x-www-form-urlencoded**
2. You need to append your security token into your password without any space. i.e. if your password is **happybirthday** and if your security token string is **86fc85296f0a712910ed88c08763795c** you will write **happybirthday86fc85296f0a712910ed88c08763795c** as your password.

If you don't have your security token you can reset that from following screen.

[image]

Comment: thanks, i have tried this this is resulting in  {
error: "unsupported_grant_type"
error_description: "grant type not supported"
}.I have appended security token too for the password

Comment: it seems like you are doing GET request instead of POST request. Please do POST request. I can see same error if I change from POST to GET ;)

Comment: i am doing POST request only... but will there be any problem with CallBackURL. Because i have checked all headers, they seems to be fine

Comment: Callback URL do not have any effect on that.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you enter all details in the Post Form Category but not in the Get Form in the Advanced Rest Client. [image]